Equivalent of Solaris "croinfo -hO Dc" command in Linux
In a past I used script in Solaris 11. In this script I used command croinfo -hO Dc (croinfo standing for chassis, receptacle, occupants information). It generated output:
root@my-host:~# croinfo -hO Dc
/dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/disk:c2t1d0
/dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD0/NVME/hba:
/dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk:c1t1d0
/dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD1/NVME/hb
.... more ...

Now I need to run this script in Linux. The script will fail because croinfo command does not exist it Linux. I need exact croinfo -hO Dc like output to parse it and get required information.
Is there an equivalent of Solaris "croinfo" command in Linux? I could not find such command. Is it possible to use several Linux commands to get croinfo -hO Dc-like output (where -O Dc requests devchassis-type and occupant-compdev in a parseable way and -h suppresses the headers)?

It would probably help more if you told us what that output actually is rather than mantra-like repeat that you need that output. It doesn't seem likely: the output you're getting seems to be device paths; and Linux and solaris are rather different in terms of representing devices. So, chances are, what you want is logically impossible. The analogy that comes to my head is "How do I change the spark plugs on my electric car?". So, tell us, exactly, what the output of that program actually tells you.

The command is bind to Oracle hardware so I see little sense to run it on other operating system.

@TestDeveloper we don't care about the exact output: We need to tell what the output represents. Is it a list of the last restaurants you had dinner at? Devices that have crashed in the past? Devices with less than 10 letters in their name? We don't know, so we can't tell you what the equivalent program is.

Voting to close as lacking any detail that would allow us to answer the question.

The full croinfo output is large  ( 15K+ characters) and I cannot put it in comment. The Linux I am switching to is Oracle Linux. And correct - I use Oracle hardware.

The output shows details of HDDs/NVME/SSDs in drive enclosure, details for PCIEs (network) other HW. Examples:/dev/chassis/ORACLE-DE3-24C.2431NMQ80E/HDD0/disk:c0t5000CCA2BE543E88d0, /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/PCIE7/NET0/pci:mlxne0, /dev/chassis/SYS/DBP/HDD1/NVME/disk:c1t1d0, /dev/chassis/SYS/MB/FM2/F0/fan:

/dev/chassis/ORACLE-DE3-24C.2431NMQ80E/IOM0/EXPANDER0/smp:smp/expd4
/dev/chassis/ORACLE-DE3-24C.2431NMQ80E/IOM0/ses:es/ses3

@TestDeveloper, linux is linux. The question is why do not stay with Solaris. And as this is very specific hardware information you can't expect to have such tools in linux. Just realize what kind of information you need and then ask how to get this info in linux (if you insist to replace Solaris)

This command generates some info: "lsblk -a -o name,model,size,serial" but it is not exactly what I need.

what is it that you exactly need? We keep asking you this for half an hour now. Describe in human words what the information is you need.

And [edit] your question to provide this information — don’t post it in comments.

Linux has no direct equivalent to croinfo. A lot of this info can be found in /sys and /dev, and then you can format it how you like. For example, to get the NVMe info as shown in your question, you can look at what's in /sys/class/nvme/. Likewise, for identifying devices with specific details on their slots or controllers, you can explore paths in /sys/class/scsi_host, /sys/class/block, or /sys/class/scsi_disk.
For instance, suppose you want to locate details about a specific NVMe device. You can find information about its controller and other specifics under /sys/class/nvme:
ls /sys/class/nvme/nvme0/

This directory contains links to subdirectories that provide details about the NVMe device’s controller, namespace, and things like PCI information.
As one example which you can extrapolate to other kinds of hardware, to identify the slot or PCI information for nvme0n1, follow the symbolic link from /sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device to its PCI slot:
% readlink -f /sys/class/nvme/nvme0/device
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/0000:02:00.0

The path shows the exact PCI address, which you can use to look up additional details, including things like slot location.
For SCSI disks (eg. /dev/sda) you can find more information in /sys/class/scsi_disk, and so on for other hardware devices.
Using data like this, you can mimic the croinfo output by extracting the data and formatting it as appropriate.

Chris, Linux can't provide a lot of information like chassi, racks, etc. For me try of OP to replace it is causa perduta.
